# How to use Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync in WPF desktop app

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, geolocation, desktop-bridge

I've built a WPF app in C# which needs to know the user's location, and currently requires that it be entered manually. I'm using the Desktop Bridge to make it be able to run as a UWP app. When it's running as a UWP app, I want to take advantage of the Windows 10 location API if it is enabled. I'm using the following code to request for location access when the program starts:

```
public static async void RequestAccess()
{
    var accessStatus = await Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();

    switch (accessStatus)
    {
        case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed:
            UwpDesktop.hasLocationAccess = true;
            break;
        case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.GeolocationAccessStatus.Denied:
            UwpDesktop.hasLocationAccess = false;
            break;
        case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.GeolocationAccessStatus.Unspecified:
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to access Windows 10 location API", "Error");
            UwpDesktop.hasLocationAccess = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

However I get the following error when I run my app if the location permission is not enabled for it:

> System.Exception: 'Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)'

The cause of this error as far as I can tell is that the `RequestAccessAsync` function needs to be run in the main UWP UI thread. The reason it only happens when the location permission is not enabled is because Windows tries to launch a UWP dialog requesting that the user grant location access, but fails to do so in a Desktop Bridge app.

I'm aware of two solutions to this problem. One would be to launch the Location section of the Settings app and show a messagebox to users asking them to grant location access there, which could work but I would really prefer to use the official API. The other option is to create a new UWP code project and write this code there, and then run it from the WPF app.

Microsoft has some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extend) that is supposed to explain how to do the second option, but their examples are complicated and I don't know how to apply them to what I'm trying to do. I don't want to create a XAML UI or a background service, all I need is a way to safely call `RequestAccessAsync` and return a value based on the outcome. I'm wondering if I really need to create a UWP project to make this behave the way I want, or what the simplest way would be to go about it.

Comment: Does your WPF app use the UWP Geolocator API, then convert the WPF app to UWP? Could you provide a simple sample to help me see your issue?

Comment: What happens if you don't request access and just go ahead and try to get the location info? Since the WPF app runs at full trust I believe you shouldn't be required to call the RequestAccessAsync API.